# How to test PHP socket TCP/IP Server using Terminal/PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I have a server up online, and I made a simple TCP/IP Server using PHP to handle a certain port. The code I use is found below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to wait for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Activate the implicit exit dump, so we'll see what we're getting
* while messages come. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '123.456.789.123';
$port = 1234;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

//clients array
$clients = array();

do {
    $read = array();
    $read[] = $sock;

    $read = array_merge($read,$clients);

    $write = NULL;
    $except = NULL;
    $tv_sec = 5;

    // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
    if(socket_select($read, $write, $except, $tv_sec) < 1)
    {
        //    SocketServer::debug("Problem blocking socket_select?");
        echo "socket continuing";
        continue;
    }

    // Handle new Connections
    if (in_array($sock, $read)) {        

        if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
            echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
            break;
        }
        $clients[] = $msgsock;
        $key = array_keys($clients, $msgsock);

        $msg = "\Welcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "You are the customer number: {$key[0]}\n" .
        "To exit, type 'quit'. To close the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    }

    // Handle Input
    foreach ($clients as $key => $client) { // for each client        
        if (in_array($client, $read)) {
            if (false === ($buf = socket_read($client, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
                echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($client)) . "\n";
                break 2;
            }
            if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($buf == 'quit') {
                unset($clients[$key]);
                socket_close($client);
                break;
            }
            if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
                socket_close($client);
                break 2;
            }
            $talkback = "Client {$key}: You said '$buf'.\n";
            socket_write($client, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
            echo "$buf\n";
        }

    }        
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

The script just basically runs and allows for more than one connection to run. After uploading the code to the server, I connected to the server, got to the directory where the file is, and then ran `php filename.php`. It does not show any warning or errors.

However, I need to further configure this TCP/IP Server and do things based on the input it receives. Right now, when I run `php filename.php`, it doesn't show anything (I'm guessing because all the outputs are written to the socket, and not echoed).

How do I test this TCP/IP Server that I made? `telnet` is out of the question since it's not secure. Right now I'm looking for nothing too complicated, so the Terminal or another simple PHP File would be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [react/socket](https://packagist.org/packages/react/socket) for your testing purposes. It allows to create clients and servers pretty fast. Try this client code just to get started:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$connector = new React\Socket\Connector($loop);

$connector->connect('127.0.0.1:1234')->then(function (React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $conn) use ($loop) {

    $conn->on('data', function ($data) use ($conn) {

        echo $data;

        $conn->close();
    });
});

$loop->run();
```

The documentation is [here](https://github.com/reactphp/socket).

Comment: How do I install ReactPHP?

Comment: @Razgriz use [composer](https://getcomposer.org): `composer require react/socket`